# QuickFix Acceptor Setting heartbeat to 0

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixn

I have created a quickfix application in C#. When the initiator connects to the acceptor, I get a log message that the acceptor has set the heartbeat to 0 seconds before the logon is sent.

I have varified that the session setting are correct and being parsed correctly by both initiator and acceptor.

Here are the settings:

[image]

[image]

Acceptor logs:

[image]

[image]

Initiator logs:

[image]

[image]

It is my understanding that the heart beat int is set at when the logon is exchanged so I dont understand why the log entry shows the heart beat being set before logon received.

And I can not get to the bottom of why it is setting the heartbeat to 0 when in the session settings it is set to 16.

Any help much appriciated.

Comment: Sounds strange. What happens when you let the session stay connected? Are heartbeats exchanged after 16 seconds? Maybe the log message is just wrong and can be ignored?

Comment: HI Christoph, That is exaclty what happens, I set up a test and the session stays stable with heartbeats going out as expected every 16 seconds, looks like a floored log message. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Despite the log message, the heartbeats were being exchanged as expected and the session is stable. The log message can be ignored.

Comment: https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/blob/21a4e85cedafc9c63895ef3377290cc9c7ce39fa/QuickFIXn/SocketReader.cs#L225  Looks like a known bug to me here. :) It has a FIXME annotation.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing.  I didn't even know that was in there.  I'm going to take care if it when next I can: https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/issues/813

Comment: Fixed.  Will be in any release after 1.11.2: https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/pull/814